# Can I store previous data and access it if new data cannot be obtained?

Tags: php, if-statement, curl, reference, storage

I am new to coding and trying to complete a task using PHP. I am scraping a web page on my company's web server which displays a count I need. However, if the user logs out of this page, the page length is much shorter and the data I require is no longer there. If the tag length is smaller than a certain amount, I would like to refer to the last data I obtained from the scrape. When new data is there, I know they are moving forward and the count will be there, but if not it breaks my code. If the data is there, that is, if the tag length is greater than 100, I would like to update the stored data. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Save the old data in a variable. If you can't get new data, keep using the old data.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Have you tried anything? It's hard to work with only a description. But as mentioned above, if you store the previously scraped data somewhere, then you can simply load that instead, if your code detects there was no usable information on the newly scraped page.

Comment: Thank you  for your suggestions. Basically when I open the page I created if the data I scrape is not there it fails, so I wanted to refer to the last data it had retrieved. I know there is no code to show I was more hoping to open a dialog. I have been learning coding for about 9 months now this was my first attempt at a public question and I am a bit nervous about it I guess. I found myself unsure of how to ask this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a test file.

```
if($scrape->length >= 100){
  $file = fopen("tfile.txt", "c");
  fseek($file, -3, SEEK_END);
  fwrite($file, $scrape);
  fclose($file);}
else{            
  $file = fopen("tfile.txt", "rb");
  $scrape = substr(fread($file, filesize("tfile.txt")), -3, 3);
  fclose($file);}
```

Comment: ....and does it work? Its a bit unclear if this is a solution (although it's posted as an Answer) or just intended to try and enhance the question. If the latter, please edit the question instead, because stackoverflow isn't structured like a discussion forum- see also the [tour], [ask] and [answer]

Comment: My mistake. Yes this does work I apologize for not clarifying. I did intend to use this as a bit of a discussion platform. I was just trying to understand what method I should use. I will consult other means in the future. Thank you again for taking the time to respond. Sorry again for the poor etiquette.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found a workable solution. If others think they have a better or alternative approach, they will add their own answers. So it's not so much a discussion as a question followed by a series of competing (and occasionally complementing) answers